# Error on variable after assignment?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, namespaces

I'm having some problems with a function. It is a part of a program for writing notes, identified by an `Id`. Notes are saved in a txt file, with the structure:

```
Open
Id
Title
Message
Close
```

This function is meant to find an `Id`, get its line number in the file and later delete it by copying it into a temporary file. I'm having a failure: the `linea_buscada` variable us being used before assignment in this line:

```
linea == linea_buscada-1
```

What an I missing? Does "with" creates a new namespace? If that's the problem, what is the best way to achieve my goal? I'm thinking about a global variable or list append, but both of them seem too weird for just storing an integer. Thank you for the help in advance.

```
@staticmethod
def eliminar_nota(ID = None):
    ID = str(ID) or input('ID?: ')
    linea = 1
    try:
        with open('temp.txt', 'x+') as archivo_temporal:
            with open("notas.txt", "r") as archivo_notas:
                for line in archivo_notas:
                    linea += 1
                    archivo_temporal.write(line)
                    if ID in line:
                        linea_buscada = linea
            os.remove("notas.txt")
            archivo_temporal.seek(0,0)
            with open("notas.txt", "w") as archivo_notas:
                linea = 1
                counting = False
                for line in archivo_temporal:
                    linea += 1
                    if linea == linea_buscada - 1:
                        counting = 5
                    if not counting:
                        archivo_notas.write(line)
                    else:
                        counting -= 1
                        continue
    finally:
        os.remove('temp.txt')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like linea_buscada must not be getting initialised in:

```
if ID in line:
    linea_buscada = linea
```

otherwise it would have been assigned a value by the point of failure. I would add some print statements to check it is being set. Without your input file I cannot check myself.

If the code below fails the issue is with the first set of nested with statements that set linea_buscada.

e.g:

```
@staticmethod
def eliminar_nota(ID = None):
    ID = str(ID) or input('ID?: ')
    linea = 1
    try:
        with open('temp.txt', 'x+') as archivo_temporal:
            with open("notas.txt", "r") as archivo_notas:
                for line in archivo_notas:
                    linea += 1
                    archivo_temporal.write(line)
                    if ID in line:
                        linea_buscada = linea
                        print(linea_buscada)
            print('Si no veo nada antes aqui, hay problemas ;)')
            os.remove("notas.txt")
            archivo_temporal.seek(0,0)
            with open("notas.txt", "w") as archivo_notas:
                linea = 1
                counting = False
                for line in archivo_temporal:
                    linea += 1
                    if linea == linea_buscada - 1:
                        counting = 5
                    if not counting:
                        archivo_notas.write(line)
                    else:
                        counting -= 1
                        continue
    finally:
        os.remove('temp.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining `linea_buscada` anywhere. You need to initialize it somehow:

```
linea_buscada = 100  # Where '100' should really be the number of lines you're dealing with.
```

When this line is interpreted:

```
if linea == linea_buscada - 1:
```

What happens is that it tries to 'substitute in' the value of `linea_buscada`. It will then decrement that value by one and test to see if it equals `linea`. However, no value has been set for `linea_buscada`, so this interpretation can't happen, and you have the failure you're seeing.

Earlier in your program, you have this:

```
if ID in line:
    linea_buscada = linea
```

However, if the test `ID in line` fails (i.e. returns `false`), the `linea_buscada` cannot be set here. Before your `with open("notas.txt", "w")`, you will need to ensure that `linea_buscada` is set:

```
if linea_buscada is not null:
    # Continue with the program
```